# \elementarycharge command not recognized in siunitx package

Tags: siunitx

I'm trying to use

```
\SI{0.006}{\elementarycharge}
```

in the [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package

```
\usepackage{siunitx}.
```

The `\elementarycharge` command does not work. I'm using

```
\documentclass[prb,twocolumn,showpacs]{revtex4}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Please include your `\usepackage{siunitx}` command.

Comment: @Seamus. Ok, I updated the question. Do I need specific options to have it work?

Comment: Could you also copy and paste the error message about the command not working? And also the version of siunitx you are using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not say which version of `siunitx` you have installed. With the current release (v2), something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\SI{0.006}{\elementarycharge\per\cubic\angstrom}
\end{document}
```

should be fine. If you have version 1 then `\elementarycharge` will not be defined and you'll need

```
\newunit{\elementarycharge}{\text{\ensuremath{e}}
```

in your preamble.

Comment: The definition for `\elementarycharge` I've given here is exactly the one used by v2 of `siunitx`, by the way.

Comment: Thanks! I was using texlive 2008, now I upgraded it and it works fine. Other errors appeared due to the upgrade, but I will ask them in a separate question if I can't solve them myself.

Comment: @Nigu. If the first instants, load `siunitx` with no options then set `\sisetup{load-configurations = version-1}` to load the back-compatibility code.

Answer (score 2):

The correct use is:

```
\si{\elementarycharge}
```

All SI units, not-quite-SI units, prefixes and suffixes from `siunitx` need to be enclosed in the `\si{}` macro. See the [manual](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/siunitx.pdf) for more information and more advanced examples of use.

Dimensionless numbers and angles have their own commands for typesetting: `\num`, `\numrange`, `\numlist`, `\ang`, and they don't need to be inside the `\si` macro.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I was using it in the `\SI{}` macro. I tried `\SI{0.006}{\elementarycharge\per\AA^3}`, which does not work. So I have to resort to `\SI{0.006}{e\per\AA^3}` for the moment. Any idea?

Comment: `\SI{0.006}{\elementarycharge\per\AA^3}` works for me. Could you post a complete minimal example that produces the issue for you?

Comment: @Martin. I will update it once I'm back on that computer.

Comment: @Martin. Using `\AA^3` will force 'literal' mode in your unit. That might be what you want, but I usually recommend sticking with 'semantic' units so that the various formatting options can be applied.

Comment: @Joseph Sure, I just used what Nigu tried to see whether this replicated the problem.

Comment: @Martin. I suspected that, but thought it was at least worth making a note. Both forms should be fine, of course, provided `\elementarycharge` is defined (_i.e._ with version 2 of `siunitx`).